# Cell value in sheet printing as datetime.datetime but not as date values - Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, datetime, openpyxl, spreadsheet

I have a excel sheet, with values:

```html
Date          Item 
01-12-2019    Car
02-12-2019    Truck
```

I opened this file in openpyxl and wanted to write the rows into a text file.
I used the following code to to that:

```py
wb = load_workbook(filename)
sheet = wb.active

report = open('textfile.txt', 'w+')


i=0
while i <= sheet.max_row:
    data = list(cell.value for cell in list(sheet.rows)[i])
    report.write(data)
    report.write('\n')
    i +=1
```

The output of this code is coming out to be :

```py
[datetime.datetime(2019,1,12,0,0), Car]
[datetime.datetime(2019,2,12,0,0), Truck]
```

but i would like the output to b:

```py
[2019-12-01, Car]
[2019-12-02, Truck]
```

So I want date values instead of datetime.datetime thing printing in the file as this report will be seen by the users.

What should I change. thanks

Answer (score 0):

openpyxl can use [datetime](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datetime.html) objects to store dates/times. Since you already have a datetime object, use datetime.strftime to write them in the format you want. See
[here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for all the format codes.

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.now()
print(d.strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
```